# stop an async forEach soon as a condition is true

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

After years of programming with JavaScript (ok, two years), I must admit I really am quite helpless understanding async operations. I understand it in theory but not in practice, and as the saying goes, in practice there is a lot of difference between theory and practice.

I have folder full of folders and files with extension '.json'. I want to evaluate the names of the files asynchronously, and when a file named "foo" (some user-supplied string) is found, I want the operation to `break` (hence async, because I don't want the program to continue once "foo" is found – it is guaranteed there is only one "foo" in the folder)

```js
// I started with a standard walk starting at directory `dir` looking 
// for a file called `str`, and run the callback `cb` on a match
const walk = function (dir, str, cb) {
    fs.readdir(dir, (error, files) => {
        if (error) throw error

        files.forEach(async (file) => {
            await evaluate(dir, file, str, cb)
        })
    })
}

const evaluate = (dir, file, str, cb) => {
    const filepath = path.join(dir, file)
    fs.stat(filepath, (error, stats) => {
        if (error) throw error

        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            walk(filepath, str, cb)
        }
        else if (stats.isFile()) {

            /* check how many times this runs */
            console.log(file)
            if (file.endsWith('.json')) {
                if (file.slice(0, -5) === str) {
                    cb(str)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

const cb = (str) => console.log(`found ${str}`)
walk('dir', '0A2f32343df3f3df3', cb)

// prints out
// 7842343df3f3df3.json
// 0A2f32343df3f3df3.json
// found 0A2f32343df3f3df3
// C342343df3f3df3.json
```

If I did it right, the last line wouldn't have printed as the operation would have stopped soon as a match was found. Of course, in my test example, I have only four files but in real world implementation, I will have 100s of 1000s of files. So it is very impt to do the least amount of work to find the truthy condition.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. forEach is not meant to handle async iterations, use `for..of` loop. forEach does not wait for async operations to happen. it keeps on iterating, irrespective of the type of callback( function that you have passed into it).

Comment: You could have a flag `bFound=false;` declared at the module level, and set it to `true` when the file is found. In the `walk` and `evaluate` functions check at convenient points  to see if `bFound` is true and if so simply return immediately, abandoning any further search activity.

Comment: To really understand `async` functions, you must first be sure you understand Promises. `async` is syntactic shorthand for writing a function returning a Promise. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Abhishekchandel I don't want `forEach` to *wait for async operations* because if it did, the operations wouldn't be async. I just want `forEach` to stop when the async operation creates a truthy condition. Using `for … of` wouldn't help because while it would let me `break` the loop, the evaluation inside the loop would be synchronous rather than async

Comment: @punkish whenever you say await, that function pauses there until the promise is resolved/rejected. so when I say wait, above is what I meant. async means not blocking event-loop that's it. await does not block it.

Comment: @Abhishekchandel and that is what he wanted - non-blocking calls in parallel... The code `files.forEach(async (file) => {await evaluate(dir, file, str, cb})})` and `files.forEach(f => evaluate(dir, f, str, cb))` is identical - but only in that special case... either way, the promise result is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You create potentially unlimited `fs.stat()` and `fs.readdir` - might want to look into a queuing or pooling mechanism - otherwise you might hit a `ulimit` for slow drives, large directories and fast CPUs.

Anyways, js promises can't be canceled natively, so you need a workaround. In your case a global `let stop = false`, a `stop = true` before calling the `cb` and in the `files.forEach` add a `ìf (!stop) {}` around the `evaluate`-call.

(I don't recommend globals, capsule in an object/class for production code.)